# Laravel and react not displaying component on page on certain path

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I have a code below

**app.js**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes React and other helpers. It's a great starting point while
 * building robust, powerful web applications using React + Laravel.
 */

import './bootstrap';

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh React component instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Index from './components/Index';

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    const app = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));

    app.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
            </Router>
        </React.StrictMode>
    )
}
```

Basically on route (/) it should display index component but it's not showing up for some reason.

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
        </div>
        <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried using react router but it's not working with what I currently have.

Comment: <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
Try this

Comment: Still not working